# Increasing the font size of a word

Tags: fonts, fontsize, amsbook

I want to increase just the font size of the word `Hello`, more than the specific size provided by `\Huge`, in the document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}

\begin{document}
{\Huge Hello} world!
\end{document}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
{\Huge Hello} world!

\scalebox{5}{Hello} world!
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

I hope `\documentstyle` is a typo, because the command has been deprecated for about a quarter of a century.

Since you're using `amsbook`, you have `\larger`:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\begin{document}

{\larger Hello} world!

{\larger[2]Hello} world!

{\larger[3]Hello} world!

{\larger[4]Hello} world!

{\larger[5]Hello} world!

\end{document}
```

[image]

I hope that `\documentstyle` is a typo: the command has been deprecated for 25 years.

If you want to scale at arbitrary sizes the default Computer Modern, you need to load `fix-cm`.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{amsbook}

\newcommand{\size}[2]{{\fontsize{#1}{0}\selectfont#2}}
\newenvironment{sizepar}[2]
 {\par\fontsize{#1}{#2}\selectfont}
 {\par}

\begin{document}

Hello world! \size{20}{Hello} \size{30}{Hello} \size{40}{Hello} world!

\begin{sizepar}{20}{26}
A paragraph typeset at 20pt size
A paragraph typeset at 20pt size
A paragraph typeset at 20pt size
A paragraph typeset at 20pt size
\end{sizepar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first argument to `sizepar` is the font size, the second argument is the baselineskip (in points if no unit is specified, which is possible, so also `\begin{sizepar}{1cm}{1.4cm}` is legal).

Comment: And How can I use <b>\larger</b> with other document classes? Or is there any equivalent command that make some words larger??

Comment: @AliAshja' There's the package `relsize`

Answer (score 3):

or

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}% <--- with latex2e is "documentstyle" deprecated
\usepackage{lmodern}  %<---

\begin{document}
{\fontsize{88}{104}\selectfont Hello} world!
\end{document}
```

[image]